# When using cypress automation the Website gets log out before last it block

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress, browser-automation, cypress-custom-commands

I am using Cypress to automate this website https://admin.britex.pw/

The issue occurs when during automation after a few It blocks, on click of a link (anchor) tag, the website gets logged out. I cannot understand why this happens as if I browse the website manually, it works fine.

The issue occurs after this command in my code:

`cy.get('table#table tbody tr').first().find('td').eq(2).find('a').click();`

But this is not related to testIsolation:false as it is already false and It happens only after that click(). if I skip .click() from above command, it works fine.

Expected:
I just want to click and interact and then perform actions.

```
describe('', () => {
    before(() => {
        Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
            return false;
        });
        cy.clearCookies();
        cy.clearLocalStorage();
        cy.clearAllSessionStorage();
        //cy.viewport(1920, 1080);
    });

    it('Visit Admin dashboard', () => {
        cy.visit("https://admin.britex.pw", { failOnStatusCode: false });
        cy.wait(3000);
    });

    it('Login as Admin', () => {
        cy.loginAdmin('gulraiz@gmail.com', '12345678');
    });

    it('Selecting Teltik Test as Company', () => {
        cy.get('.custom-select[name="company"]').select('1');
        cy.wait(2000);
        cy.get('.swal-button').click();
        cy.wait(6300);
    });

    it('Selecting user to create a custom invoice', () => {
        cy.get('.form-control#validationDefaultUsername')
            .should('be.visible')
            .clear()
            .type('muhammadafnan.senarios@gmail.com');

        cy.get('li>.searchEmail').click({ force: true });
        cy.wait(3000);

        cy.get('table#table tbody tr').first().invoke('text').then((value) => {
            cy.log('Value in Second Column:', value);

            // Now, re-select the first row and click the link without using alias
            cy.get('table#table tbody tr').first().find('td').eq(2).find('a').click();
            cy.wait(5000); // Add a delay
        }).debug();
    });

    it('Selecting Billing tab and creating a custom invoice', () => {
        cy.get('#billing-tab').click();
        cy.wait(2000);
        cy.get('#payment_type[name="payment_type"]').select('Custom Invoice');
        cy.get('#invoice_type[name="invoice_type"]').select('Create New Invoice');
        cy.get('#usage_type[name="type"]').select('One Time');
        cy.get('.subscription_id').select(':nth-child(2)');
        cy.get('#amount').type('100');
        cy.get('#description').type('test');
        cy.wait(1500);
        cy.get('.btn.btn1.sendbtn2[type="submit"]').click();
        cy.wait(2000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you provide clarification on what you mean by "it blocks"? Do you mean it goes back to login? Is there a message in the dev console?

Comment: What error caused you to use `Cypress.on('uncaught:exception')`?